# Ncalc divide decimal by decimal

Tags: c#, double, decimal, ncalc

Is there a way to divide a decimal by another decimal in Ncalc?

When I try

```
Expression exp = new Expression("119 / 1.19");
    try
    {
        MessageBox.Show(exp.Evaluate().ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "ERROR");
    }
```

I get:

> "Operator '/' can't be applied to operands of type 'decimal' and 'double'".

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Got 100 in MessageBox. What version of Ncalc?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code that errors out? Looks like you are dividing an integer and a double, not two decimals, and your error code says a double and a decimal, I'm confused on where the error actually is.

Comment: I've cleaned my project and now is it working. Strange

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Double`

Like this

```
System.Double amount = 11000.19;
Expression ex = new Expression("Amount*0.2");
ex.Parameters.Add("Amount", amount);
object result = ex.Evaluate();
```